# Excel doesn't recognize dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I open clean workbook and type in `2021-12-14` or any other format it will not recognize is as a date.
When I type `42560` and change it to date number format I can display it as desired eg `9th of July 2016`. In formula bar it changes from `42560` to `2016-07-09`. Then if I change date in formula bar to anything else, it does not recognize it anymore and simply what is in formula bar instead.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please post online an example workbook (OneDrive, Dropbox etc).

Comment: Ensure that the format of the cell is General before you type anything. If it is text, it will not convert whatever you type.

Comment: I'm not much of an Excel user, but doesn't it require slashes to recognise dates? dd/mm/yy etc

Comment: Here is example of my file https://www.uschovna.cz/zasilka/SZVCXAD5B8KVP8EB-FK5/ @harrymc

Comment: Could you add to your post a screenshot of *Control Panel > Region > Formats*? What is your Office version?

Comment: @Tetsujin it depends on the date format of the current locale. Some use `dd.mm.yyyy`, some use `dd-mm-yyyy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your spreadsheet, cells A1 (your cell with `2021-12-14` in it, just typing over it), A2, and A3, I have no problem at all. Even cell A1 displays my typing of `2021-12-14` as a date.

That pretty much means, since it did not work that way for you, that you are running afoul of a basic logic issue in the situation.

Excel must KNOW to treat, or to decide to treat, an entry as a date. So, while it seems `2021-12-14` and `horse` should get different treatment, or at least, you are not amazed if Excel treats the entries differently, the truth is that to Excel they are the same thing, more or less, with nothing indication one is a date and one is not.

Excel takes that indication from your operating system's settings for dates (Windows 10 in my case). If the OS is set to recognize a given string type as a date and treat it as such, then Excel will be set to do the same as it looks to those settings for its own use.

So, you entered the string and got a text treatment. I entered it and got a date treatment. Same cell, same everything. Except my operating system settings include that kind of string being a possible date form. So my Excel interprets it so and treats it like a date.

However, if I enter `20211214` which I consider a date format though obtuse and hard to read, I get a number in the cell, but it is not treated as a date. (That form is useful outside Excel in programs that do not use Excel's "how many days after the start date" method of defining dates... date math using your data work. But still obtuse and hard to read.)

No matter how sure you are that your system has settings that should consider a string like `2021-12-14`, it is easy enough to check on. It may be something else, but I doubt it due to the very same cell working differently on my system

Comment: Hi and thank you!
Yes it was the issue. so I am using custom date and time in my Win10 which actually is yyyy-mm-dd and hhmm. When I reset that setting back to original Excel works. It was long time since i changed that and guess I was not doing any operations with dates in Excel since then.